# Find specific bit value in c# binary string

Tags: c#, binary

Is there any solution to find a specific binary bit value inside a string representation of a binary number?
For example, I have a binary string with 64 bit length:

```
0000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000100001001000000000
```

I need to find and return the value in the 28th bit, starting from the left. In the example above, it's equal to `1`.

Comment: Q: Homework?  Q: What could be easier than 1) an array, 2) the binary value of one digit at a time?  Or, if you only want one bit ... then access the array offset directly?

Comment: This is @"Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask" registry key binary value ! And i need found existing values.

Comment: with examples from other guys , i found other values from binary string !

Comment: @paulsm4 i write small winos tweaker !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int val = s[28 - 1] - '0';  ///////
```

Comment: Simpliest way to solve my question ! And works great ! Thanks alot !

Comment: Interesting way, didn't realize subtracting characters actually subtracts their Unicode values. Of course, let's hope the binary string isn't composed of the boldish numbers toward the end of unicode table: ５２８４９１

Answer (score 1):

Well, the value on `28`th bit *from the left* is the `2^36` for the value of `64` bit (64-28).

So just make a binary `&` with your value and if it's changed, means that on `28`th from the left was a `0`, if not was a `1`

```
long value = ... 
//binary rapresentation value is (say) 

0000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000100001001000000000
```

so , if

```
if(value & 2^36 != value) //binary AND 
    return 0; //28th was 0
else
    return 1; //28th was 1
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: @user1562839: I'm afraid here is not much choice then using simple binary operations

Comment: @user1562839, the point made by this answer is that you should not use strings to represent binary data. It's inappropriate, not to mention massively inefficient. Once that's been established, the only way to work with numbers in binary is via simple bit operations!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a language barrier here, but this sounds like a good place for indexOf? If you need to take a specific portion of a string I might do this:

```
//string array for example
foreach(string BinaryString in BinaryStrings[])
{
  string TwentyEightBitSub = BinaryString.SubString(28);
  if(TwentyEightBitSub.indexOf("00000010") != -1)
  {
    //do something with matched string 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know that the string will be 64 bits (leading zeros never absent), then this will work:

```
private int getBit(string binString, int index) {
    if (binString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("binString");
    if (binString.Length != 64)
        throw new ArgumentException("binString was not of length 64.", "binString");
    if (index < 0 || index > 63)
        throw new ArgumentException("index was not in [0,63]", "index");

    char theBit = binString[binString.Length - (1 + index)];
    if (theBit == '0')
        return 0;
    else if (theBit == '1')
        return 1;
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("The supplied string was not binary.", "binString");
}
```